# How to use other task while AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm practicing on async tasks. I want to use intent while the program is performing some calculation. 
I can't use the intent in onClick, probably in onProgressUpdate.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnStart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    Button btnAsync=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAsync);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAsync.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnStart:
        doLongTaskOnMain(50001);
        break;
    case R.id.btnAsync:
        LongTask task=new LongTask();
        task.execute(50000);
        break;
    }   
}

private void doLongTaskOnMain(int number){

    TextView textOutput=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
    textOutput.setText("Calculating sum of :"+number);

    long sum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<number; i++){

        sum+= i;

        textOutput.setText("Progress"+100f*i/number);           
    }   
    textOutput.setText("Sum: "+sum);        
}

class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Float, Long>{    //<Params, Progress, Result>

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        TextView textOutput=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
        textOutput.setText("Start");
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        int number= params[0];
        long sum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
            sum+=i;
            publishProgress(100f*i/number);
        }
        return sum;

    }    

    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
            Float progress=values[0];
            TextView textOutput=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
            textOutput.setText("progress "+Math.round(progress)+"%");

            Button btnNext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);


        }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            TextView textOutput=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
            textOutput.setText("sum: "+result);
        }       
    }   
}
```

The Second Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button btnBack= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);       
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How can I move to the second activity without stopping the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `AsyncTask` a standalone class, and have it an `Activity` member (better a weak reference though). Then, in your first activity's `onCreate()` you set that member to the first `Activity`, in a second `Activity`'s `onCreate()` to the 2nd activity. 
This way your `onPostExecute` will have the correct activity.

You can probably use an event bus instead such as [Green Robot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Not really a good design model. Bearing in mind the OP wants to use `publishProgress(...)`, `onProgressUpdate(...)` and `onPostExecute(...)` with various UI components, that would mean both `Activities` would need layouts with valid resource ids for the components. Bearing in mind a stand-alone `AsyncTask` (if it's meant to be re-usable by multiple `Activities`) shouldn't really know about any UI components and their resource ids.

Comment: I've edited saying an event bus is possible instead. Whatever.

Comment: While the example in the question doesn't make much sense, the question seems to be on how to _start_ a second `Activity` from an `AsyncTask`.